# Nested ForEach in ADF (Azure Data Factory)

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image: Pipeline ADF]I have a set of json files that I want to browse, in each file there is a field that contains a list of links that direct to an image. The goal is to download each image from the links using binary formats (I tested with several links and it already works).
Here, my problem is to make the nested ForEach, I manage to browse all the json files but when I make a second ForEach to browse the links and make a copy data to download the images using an Execute Pipeline I get this error

**"ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=cannot reference action 'Copy data1'. Action 'Copy data1' must either be in 'runAfter' path, or be a Trigger"**

Example of file:

t1.json

```
{
   "type": "jean",
   "image":[
      "pngmart.com/files/7/Denim-Jean-PNG-Transparent-Image.png",
      "https://img2.freepng.fr/20171218/882/men-s-jeans-png-image-5a387658387590.0344736015136497522313.jpg",
      "https://img2.freepng.fr/20171201/ed5/blue-jeans-png-image-5a21ed9dc7f436.281334271512172957819.jpg"
   ]
}
```

t1.json

```
{
   "type": "socks",
   "image":[ "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Fun_socks.png/667px-Fun_socks.png",
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Bulk_tube_socks.png",
      "https://cdn.picpng.com/socks/socks-face-30640.png"
   ]
}
```

Do you have a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mr incognito, can you share more information/snip of how you have configured the second foreach activity in the pipeline and copy data in execute pipeline?

Comment: Hi @NiharikaMoola-MT to give you an idea, this is how I structured my Pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have repro’d and was able to copy all the links looping the `copy data` activity inside the `ForEach` activity and using the `execute pipeline` activity.

**Parent pipeline:**

1. If you have multiple JSON files, get the files list using the `Get Metadata` activity.

[image]

[image]

2. Loop the child items using the `ForEach` activity and add the `execute pipeline` activity to get the data from each file by passing the current item as a parameter (`@item().name`).

[image]

**Child pipeline:**

3. Create a **parameter** to store the file name from the parent pipeline.

[image]

4. Using the `lookup` activity, get the data from the current JSON file.

Filename property: `@pipeline().parameters.filename`

[image]

[image]

Here I have added `https://` to your first image link as it is not validating in the copy activity and giving an error.

5. Pass the output to the `ForEach` activity and loop through each image value.

`@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].image`

[image]

6. Add Copy data activity inside ForEach activity to copy each link from source to sink.
7. I have created a **binary** dataset with the `HttpServer` linked service and created a parameter for the Base URL in the linked service.
8. Passing the linked service parameter value from the dataset.

[image]

9. Pass the dataset parameter value from the copy activity source to use the current item (link) in the linked service.

[image]

Comment: Thank for you answer, I have found a similary solution. Instead of the meta data I browse each file in the folder with a look up, what is the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity#limitations-and-workarounds) you **cannot** nest For Each activities in Azure Data Factory (ADF) or Synapse Pipelines, but you can use the [Execute Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) activity to create nested pipelines, where the parent has a For Each activity and the child pipeline does too.  You can also chain For Each activities one after the other, but not nest them.

Excerpt from the documentation:

| Limitation | Workaround |
| --- | --- |
| You can't nest a ForEach loop inside another ForEach loop (or an Until loop). | Design a two-level pipeline where the outer pipeline with the outer ForEach loop iterates over an inner pipeline with the nested loop. |

Or visually:

[image]

It may be that multiple nested pipelines is not what you want in which case you could pass this looping off to another activity, eg Stored Proc, Databricks Notebook, Synapse Notebook (if you're in Azure Synapse Analytics) etc.  One example here might be to load up the json files into a table (or dataframe), extract the filenames once and then loop through that list, rather than each file.  Just an idea.

Comment: Thank for your answer @wBob, this is what I did but I have the error that I said above and I don't know how to fix this for the moment. In the case "Some activity" I have a copy data

Comment: Have you edited the json behind your pipeline?  This can sometimes cause this type of problem.  Consider rolling back via source code control to when it last worked or just start again, and build up bit by bit.

Comment: I edit my first post so you can see a picture of each element of my pipelines. 
Yes I did a data flow on the original file because there was several fields and I wanted to keep some on new json file.
However, this version of the code with the two foreach never worked. I had a similar experience but I only needed one ForEach because there was a single link per product (no list) and it worked.

Comment: This is just debugging.  Create a new pipeline that does the Lookup only.  Does it work?  If so, add a For Each activity that loops through the Lookup output, but only has a Set Variable Activity inside it.  Does it work?  If so, add an Execute Pipeline activity that points to a simple pipeline that only has a Set Variable activity in it.  Does it work?  Keep going, work out where the error is introduced.

Comment: Thank you. Know I know where is the error "Operation on target ForEach1 failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed", it's in the copy data. I think that he doesn't understand how to loop on the list and correctly select the links in the list