# Data Factory: how to stop pipeline execution without logic and without failure?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a simple pipeline consisting of:

- A notebook, when completed successfully followed by;
- A ForEach loop.

When executed successfully, the notebook either outputs:

1. An array of values for the ForEach loop (no issue here).
2. A message that some conditions are not met (troublesome part).

In situation two a string is passed to the ForEach loop, which causes the activity to fail. This is not the desired result, because the pipeline should run successfully.

I have tried to solve the issue with the Switch activity, but you can not put a ForEach activity in a Switch. The same issue arises when I try to use the If Condition activity.

Any solutions and workarounds are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity#limitations-and-workarounds), For-each activity **cannot**  be nested inside **if activity or switch activity** in Azure Data Factory (ADF). Instead, use the  [Execute Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity)  activity to create nested pipelines, where the parent has If activity and the child pipeline has for-each activity.

| Limitation | Workaround |
| --- | --- |
| You can't nest a ForEach loop inside another ForEach loop (or an Until loop). | Design a two-level pipeline where the outer pipeline with the outer ForEach loop iterates over an inner pipeline with the nested loop. |

Refer the NiharikaMoola-MT's answer on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684969/nested-foreach-in-adf-azure-data-factory).
In the parent pipeline, keep **Notebook activity** and **If activity**. Then invoke the child pipeline with **for-each activity** inside the true section of If activity.